# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) php and angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to connect with Mamp which is local server but I got this error 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

if you could help me to fix this error.

Php code :

```
<?php
//insert.php

$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $student_Id = mysql_real_escape_string($data->student_Id);
    $lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->lastName);
    $firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->firstName);
    $grade = mysql_real_escape_string($data->grade);
    $gender = mysql_real_escape_string($data->gender);

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("SchoolTeam");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Student (`student_Id`, `lastName`, `firstName`, `grade`, `gender`) VALUES ('".$student_Id."', '".$lastName."', '".$firstName."', '".$grade."','".$gender."')");
?>
```

Comment: here is PhP code:

Comment: Please post your Angular.js code and any other useful code, as well. Could you perhaps format the PHP properly?